# package does not exist error while using maven install command

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a java maven project

my pom.xml file is as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.csam.enabling</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>core</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>140</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
        <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
        <version>1.7R3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-reactor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am trying to build a jar file using **mvn clean install** command from command prompt.
but it is giving me error like

```
  [ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[5,30] package org.hibernate.criterion does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[6,25] package org.hibernate.type does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[19,55] package Example does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[33,67] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Type
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.dao.selectors.DefaultPropertySelector
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[5,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[6,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[7,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[8,31] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[23,47] cannot find symbol
symbol: class JsonDeserializer
public class MTPJsonStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[26,27] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JsonParser
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonStringDeserializer
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[27,27] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[13,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[14,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[15,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[16,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[17,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[18,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[19,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[84,33] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CompilerEnvirons
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[84,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AstRoot
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[95,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ScriptNode
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[120,24] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Node
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[232,44] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Node
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[288,35] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Node
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[3,31] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[4,51] package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[5,31] package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[8,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[9,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[10,31] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[11,36] package org.codehaus.jackson.map.type does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[12,32] package org.codehaus.jackson.type does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[13,31] package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[14,31] package org.springframework.util does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\CodecStrategy.java:[3,31] package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[18,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectMapper
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[20,22] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MediaType
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[24,11] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectMapper
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[29,25] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MediaType
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[34,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectMapper
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[30,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectMapper
location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.JsonCodecStrategy
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.959 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-11T09:42:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[5,30] package org.hibernate.criterion does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[6,25] package org.hibernate.type does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[19,55] package Example does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\dao\selectors\DefaultPropertySelector.java:[33,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Type
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.dao.selectors.DefaultPropertySelector
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[5,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[6,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[7,27] package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[8,31] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[23,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class JsonDeserializer
[ERROR] public class MTPJsonStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[26,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class JsonParser
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonStringDeserializer
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[27,27] package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonStringDeserializer.java:[28,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class JsonProcessingException
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonStringDeserializer
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\util\Base64.java:[34,50] package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[8,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[9,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[10,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[11,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[12,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[13,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[14,29] package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[15,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[16,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[17,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[18,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[19,33] package org.mozilla.javascript.ast does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[84,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class CompilerEnvirons
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[84,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class AstRoot
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[95,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ScriptNode
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[120,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Node
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\rhino\RhinoUtil.java:[232,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Node
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.rhino.RhinoUtil
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[13,31] package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[14,31] package org.springframework.util does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\CodecStrategy.java:[3,31] package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[18,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[20,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class MediaType
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[24,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[29,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class MediaType
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\MTPJsonCodecStrategy.java:[34,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.MTPJsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[30,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.JsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[44,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.JsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[79,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class JavaType
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.JsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[83,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class MediaType
[ERROR] location: class com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.codec.json.JsonCodecStrategy
[ERROR] C:\Projects\se_wallet\development\server\sprint6\core\src\main\java\com\csam\wsc\enabling\core\codec\json\JsonCodecStrategy.java:[83,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I also gave local repository path (C:\Users\ketan.patel.m2\repository) in settings.xml 
but still not able to resolve the error.
please help....
(i have not post the entire error log)

Comment: it clearly means that you haven't added required dependency and it is failing to compile because it is failing to find it

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you need to change the scope of some of your dependencies. For example, the compiler seems to be complaining about missing the `ObjectMapper` class. This likely refers to the `ObjectMapper` class within the Jackson dependency.

Try updating your dependencies as follows:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
    </dependency>
```

Also, for your reference, see the Maven documentation about dependency scope:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Chances are this change will only resolve some of the compile errors. You may have to change the scope of other dependencies through trial and error.

Comment: I had the same problem of the scope in dependency, I just removed scope and Done!!, this saved my night, great!!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the particular jar file from your local repository and run again in online mode.