# 'child_process'.exec unable to run Java Function

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I have a Java file that works in eclipse (but not in terminal using javac) however I'm trying to execute it in Node js using the `exec` library to send a response to the frontend but when I try to run the Javascript that references the Java function I get errors that my java libraries don't exist.  I've tried adding the compile scope in the dependencies config as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003570/package-does-not-exist-error-while-using-maven-install-command) but still getting the error, what else can I try?

Comment: Yes! https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback  I think it has something to do with the compile which is why the javac fails as well, but im still looking into it

Comment: so this is a nodeJS library, not a javascript function

Comment: Yes it is, completely forgot there was a distinction for a minute there

Comment: `exec` essentially just runs a command on the command line, so you'll need to find a way to run your Java program from the command line. Usually this means compiling your Java program into an executable .jar file and then running it with the `java` command on the command line. Can you do that?

Comment: I will have to look into how to create jar files, found I can supply arguments so dropping that question.  I'm finding I might have to create it using javac which is not working with these classes though are there other ways to turn individual classes into executable jars?

Comment: Thank you @drmercer with your help I have figured it out, using the export as an executable jar from eclipse and then adding the -jar modifier to the childprocesses I was able to call and receive data

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out. :)